# Flutter web with firebase messaging on unsupported broswers

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, flutter-web

My flutter site works fine on browsers supporting Firebase messaging but on browsers where its NOT supported homepage fails to load and on browser console i see the message

"Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Messaging: This browser doesn't support the API's required to use the firebase SDK. (messaging/unsupported-browser)."

i have looked at other solutions

1. did add 'firebase.messaging.isSupported() ? firebase.messaging() : null' but this does not help
2. used 'kIsWeb' and prevent any initialization or calling/registering everything related to firebase messaging but still the page does not load in unsupported browser.

it looks like somewhere the firebase messaging package its trying to get an messaging instance , i am using the same code base to build an android app as well so i dont want to remove the messaging fully is there a work around to fix this issue , any help is greately appreciated

Message:

```
Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Messaging: This browser doesn't support the API's required to use the firebase SDK. (messaging/unsupported-browser).
    c errors.ts:92
    create errors.ts:128
    <anonymous> index.ts:56
    getOrInitializeService provider.ts:194
    getImmediate provider.ts:95
    _getService firebaseApp.ts:127
    i firebaseNamespaceCore.ts:228
    n firebaseNamespaceCore.ts:209
    getMessagingInstance messaging.dart:20
    new firebase_messaging_web.dart:36
    registerWith firebase_messaging_web.dart:25
    registerPlugins generated_plugin_registrant.dart:25
    main web_entrypoint.dart:14
    runBody async_patch.dart:84
    _async async_patch.dart:123
    main$ web_entrypoint.dart:13
    dartRunMain main_module.bootstrap.js:20
    $dartRunMain main_module.bootstrap.js:19
    <anonymous> line 8764 > injectedScript:1
    runMain client.js:8764
    0 client.js:22429
    protected client.js:3793
    call$2 client.js:11010
    call$1 client.js:10996
    _rootRunUnary client.js:4118
    runUnary$2$2 client.js:12315
    call$0 client.js:11376
    _Future__propagateToListeners client.js:3905
    _completeWithValue$1 client.js:11209
    complete$1 client.js:10979
    _asyncReturn client.js:3765
    RequireRestarter_create client.js:8587
    protected client.js:3793
    call$2 client.js:11010
    call$1 client.js:10996
    _rootRunUnary client.js:4118
    runUnary$2$2 client.js:12315
    call$0 client.js:11376
    _Future__propagateToListeners client.js:3905
    _completeWithValue$1 client.js:11209
    complete$1 client.js:10979
    _asyncReturn client.js:3765
    0 client.js:22843
    protected client.js:3793
    call$2 client.js:11010
    call$1 client.js:10996
    _rootRunUnary client.js:4118
    runUnary$2$2 client.js:12315
    call$0 client.js:11376
    _Future__propagateToListeners client.js:3905
    _completeWithValue$1 client.js:11209
    complete$1 client.js:10979
    _asyncReturn client.js:3765
    0 client.js:22820
    protected client.js:3793
    call$2 client.js:11010
    call$1 client.js:10996
    _rootRunUnary client.js:4118
    runUnary$2$2 client.js:12315
    call$0 client.js:11376
    _Future__propagateToListeners client.js:3905
    _completeWithValue$1 client.js:11209
    call$0 client.js:11298
    _rootRun client.js:4103
    run$1$1 client.js:12307
    runGuarded$1 client.js:12235
    call$0 client.js:12441
    _microtaskLoop client.js:3960
    _startMicrotaskLoop client.js:3966
    call$1 client.js:10879
    invokeClosure client.js:1204
    function client.js:1223
    _AsyncRun__initializeScheduleImmediate client.js:3724
    <anonymous> client.js:24072
    getterName client.js:99
    _scheduleAsyncCallback client.js:3980
    _rootScheduleMicrotask client.js:4171
    scheduleMicrotask$1 client.js:12361
    _asyncCompleteWithValue$1 client.js:11233
    _asyncComplete$1 client.js:11227
    complete$1 client.js:11061
    complete$0 client.js:11064
    RequireRestarter_create client.js:8574
    protected client.js:3793
    call$2 client.js:11010
    _asyncStartSync client.js:3757
    RequireRestarter_create client.js:8590
    0 client.js:22398
    protected client.js:3793
    call$2 client.js:11010
    call$1 client.js:10996
    _rootRunUnary client.js:4118
    runUnary$2$2 client.js:12315
    call$0 client.js:11376
    _Future__propagateToListeners client.js:3905
    _complete$1 client.js:11200
    _cancelAndValue client.js:4060
    call$1 client.js:11468
    call$1 client.js:17396
    _rootRunUnary client.js:4124
    runUnary$2$2 client.js:12315
    runUnaryGuarded$1$2 client.js:12247
    call$1 client.js:12450
    invokeClosure client.js:1204
    function client.js:1223
    _addEventListener$3 client.js:16289
    addEventListener$3 client.js:16283
    addEventListener$3$x client.js:3596
    _tryResume$0 client.js:17369
    onData$1 client.js:17348
    get$first client.js:11429
    0 client.js:22390
    protected client.js:3793
    call$2 client.js:11010
    _asyncStartSync client.js:3757
    call$0 client.js:22434
    _rootRun client.js:4103
    run$1$1 client.js:12307
    _runZoned client.js:4235
    runZonedGuarded client.js:4225
    runZoned client.js:4212
    main client.js:8464
    <anonymous> client.js:24320
    <anonymous> client.js:24304
    dartProgram client.js:24315
    <anonymous> client.js:24322
errors.ts:92:4
    _startMicrotaskLoop schedule_microtask.dart:55
    _scheduleImmediateWithPromise async_patch.dart:166
    (Async: promise callback)
    _scheduleImmediateWithPromise async_patch.dart:164
    _scheduleImmediate async_patch.dart:136
    _scheduleAsyncCallback schedule_microtask.dart:72
    _rootScheduleMicrotask zone.dart:1257
    scheduleMicrotask zone.dart:1470
    _asyncCompleteError future_impl.dart:592
    _asyncCompleteWithErrorCallback future.dart:955
    runBody async_patch.dart:117
    _async async_patch.dart:123
    main$ web_entrypoint.dart:13
    dartRunMain main_module.bootstrap.js:20
    forEach self-hosted:206
    $dartRunMain main_module.bootstrap.js:19
    <anonymous> line 8764 > injectedScript:1
    runMain client.js:8764
    0 client.js:22429
    protected client.js:3793
    call$2 client.js:11010
    call$1 client.js:10996
    _rootRunUnary client.js:4118
    runUnary$2$2 client.js:12315
    call$0 client.js:11376
    _Future__propagateToListeners client.js:3905
    _completeWithValue$1 client.js:11209
    complete$1 client.js:10979
    _asyncReturn client.js:3765
    RequireRestarter_create client.js:8587
    protected client.js:3793
    call$2 client.js:11010
    call$1 client.js:10996
    _rootRunUnary client.js:4118
    runUnary$2$2 client.js:12315
    call$0 client.js:11376
    _Future__propagateToListeners client.js:3905
    _completeWithValue$1 client.js:11209
    complete$1 client.js:10979
    _asyncReturn client.js:3765
    0 client.js:22843
    protected client.js:3793
    call$2 client.js:11010
    call$1 client.js:10996
    _rootRunUnary client.js:4118
    runUnary$2$2 client.js:12315
    call$0 client.js:11376
    _Future__propagateToListeners client.js:3905
    _completeWithValue$1 client.js:11209
    complete$1 client.js:10979
    _asyncReturn client.js:3765
    0 client.js:22820
    protected client.js:3793
    call$2 client.js:11010
    call$1 client.js:10996
    _rootRunUnary client.js:4118
    runUnary$2$2 client.js:12315
    call$0 client.js:11376
    _Future__propagateToListeners client.js:3905
    _completeWithValue$1 client.js:11209
    call$0 client.js:11298
    _rootRun client.js:4103
    run$1$1 client.js:12307
    runGuarded$1 client.js:12235
    call$0 client.js:12441
    _microtaskLoop client.js:3960
    _startMicrotaskLoop client.js:3966
    call$1 client.js:10879
    invokeClosure client.js:1204
    function client.js:1223
    (Async: MutationCallback)
    _AsyncRun__initializeScheduleImmediate client.js:3724
    <anonymous> client.js:24072
    getterName client.js:99
    _scheduleAsyncCallback client.js:3980
    _rootScheduleMicrotask client.js:4171
    scheduleMicrotask$1 client.js:12361
    _asyncCompleteWithValue$1 client.js:11233
    _asyncComplete$1 client.js:11227
    complete$1 client.js:11061
    complete$0 client.js:11064
    RequireRestarter_create client.js:8574
    protected client.js:3793
    call$2 client.js:11010
    _asyncStartSync client.js:3757
    RequireRestarter_create client.js:8590
    0 client.js:22398
    protected client.js:3793
    call$2 client.js:11010
    call$1 client.js:10996
    _rootRunUnary client.js:4118
    runUnary$2$2 client.js:12315
    call$0 client.js:11376
    _Future__propagateToListeners client.js:3905
    _complete$1 client.js:11200
    _cancelAndValue client.js:4060
    call$1 client.js:11468
    call$1 client.js:17396
    _rootRunUnary client.js:4124
    runUnary$2$2 client.js:12315
    runUnaryGuarded$1$2 client.js:12247
    call$1 client.js:12450
    invokeClosure client.js:1204
    function client.js:1223
    (Async: EventListener.handleEvent)
    _addEventListener$3 client.js:16289
    addEventListener$3 client.js:16283
    addEventListener$3$x client.js:3596
    _tryResume$0 client.js:17369
    onData$1 client.js:17348
    get$first client.js:11429
    0 client.js:22390
    protected client.js:3793
    call$2 client.js:11010
    _asyncStartSync client.js:3757
    call$0 client.js:22434
    _rootRun client.js:4103
    run$1$1 client.js:12307
    _runZoned client.js:4235
    runZonedGuarded client.js:4225
    runZoned client.js:4212
    main client.js:8464
    <anonymous> client.js:24320
    <anonymous> client.js:24304
    dartProgram client.js:24315
    <anonymous> client.js:24322
```